# can i diy an asic miner?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-theory, hash, asic, sha256

Iam interested in mining bitcoin so Iam wondering if I can get a pcb for hashing and bring asic chip that algorithms are sha-256 and stick them together with some other electronics and have a control board with power supply?
If you are interested too lets make a group and start searching together to get everything done.

Comment: hey i am interested can you drop a link?

Comment: what about making a discord group to make some action

Comment: perhaps doing that would be best.

Comment: You would need to get the ASIC chips and the information about the ASIC chips. And the ASIC chips are the expensive part of the ASIC miner so what's the advantage for you?